# conditional probability, how to express P(A,B|C) in term of P(A,C|B)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

what i know is,

conditional probability:
P(X|Y) = P(X,Y) / P(Y)

total probability:
P(X) = sum Y [P(X|y)  P(y)]

bayes rule:
p(X|Y) = p(Y|X) P(X)

Is it possible to express **P(A,B|C)** in term of **P(A,C|B)** and joint distribution of two random variable, i.e. **P(A,C). P(A,B), P(B,C)**

Is it possible to express **P(A,B|C,D)** in term of **P(A,C|B, D)** and joint distribution of two random variable, **i.e. P(A,C). P(A,B), P(B,C)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for $P(AB|C)$, the answer is no.

$$P(AB|C)=\frac{P(ABC)}{P(C)}=\frac{P(AC|B)P(B)}{P(C)}=P(AC|B)\frac{P(B)}{P(C)}
=P(AC|B)\frac{P(B)}{P(C)}$$

$$\frac{P(AB|C)}{P(AC|B)}
=\frac{P(B)}{P(C)}$$

Now 
$$\frac{P(B)}{P(C)}=\frac{P(CB)/P(C|B)}{P(BC)/P(B|C)}=\frac{P(B|C)}{P(C|B)}$$

$$P(AB|C)=P(AC|B)\frac{P(B)}{P(C)}=P(AC|B)\frac{P(B|C)}{P(C|B)}$$

$P(B|C)$ and $P(C|B)$ include $P(C)$ and $P(B)$.

I think for $P(AB|CD)$, the answer is yes.
$$P(AB|CD)=\frac{P(ABCD)}{P(CD)}=\frac{P(AC|BD)P(BD)}{P(CD)}$$

Comment: then what about  P(A, C|B, D). in term of P(A, B|C, D) and joint distribution of two random variable, i.e. P(A,C). P(A,B), P(B,C), thanks a lot for insight.

Comment: In this case the answer is yes, I added this too.

Comment: thanks for teaching!